# Are there any asymmetric compression algorithms which are fast compression / slow decompression?

Tags: c, performance, compression

I have looked at many "fast compression" libraries, but all of them feature fast decompression rather than fast compression.

I am working on a system where fast compression is more highly valued than fast decompression.
Does there exist such an algorithm? If so, are there C libraries that implement it?

Update: I am compressing pages of physical memory, and I require compression throughput equal to or faster than a direct copy. I am using a detection algorithm to discover pages with low entropy to guarantee with high probability that the pages I am trying to compress are actually compressible.

Comment: The act of compressing data is inherently difficult.  It is about pattern detection, which tends to be computationally expensive unless you opt for very simple compression with poor ratios.  Maybe you could elaborate a bit.  What kind of data are you compressing?  What are your throughput requirements?  What are your expectations on compression ratios?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124239/fastest-c-file-compression-library-available

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can make anything as slow as you like, but I am not aware of any algorithms that are inherently fast at compression and slow at decompression.

If you are imagining that there is some sort of trade that would permit the compression to be faster if you allowed the decompression to be slower, then no, there isn't.

[lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) provides very fast compression, and even faster decompression.

Answer (score 2):

The [Large Text Compression Benchmark](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html) has lots of data on compression performance, including some graphs.  While it's focused on high compression it should give you a good idea of the tradeoffs involved between speed, memory usage and compression ratio.  Compressors fall broadly into two categories: symmetric ones that take similar amounts of time to compress and decompress (these tend also to be the slow ones with high compression), and asymmetric ones that are faster to decompress than to compress (these are much more popular).  In no case that I'm aware of is compression significantly faster than decompression.

The most widely used "fast" compressors I'm aware of are [snappy](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/) and [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/).  @MarkAdler mentioned [lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) which looks pretty nice too.

Comment: lz4 compresses a little better than snappy and LZO, is a little faster than LZO and a lot faster than snappy compressing, and is a lot faster than both at decompressing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [density](https://github.com/centaurean/density.git) ?

It's a BSD library with extremely fast compression speed (faster than lz4).
Decompression is also super fast, as stated in the [following benchmark](http://quixdb.github.io/squash/benchmarks/core-i3-2105.html#enwik8).

For testing there is an open source command line client named "sharc" and available on github as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to look at a compression benchmark. They report at least two numbers: compressed size and compression speed. In your case decompression speed does not matter so just look at compression speed.

A few algorithms will form the [Pareto Frontier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency). Pick one of them.